# Windows 8 webcam automatically taking a photo when it wakes up

Tags: windows-8, sleep, webcam

Is it possible to have the webcam take a picture if my computer is woken from sleep mode?

I have seen that there are some programs with motion detection, but I would prefer a method that takes a picture when the machine is clicked or key pressed

i've seen the windows 7 one but dosn't seem to be the same when i try for my laptop
Windows 8  HP accer

Comment: If you can find a program that can be automated to snap a picture using your webcam, then it should be possible to create a scheduled task that runs it when the computer wakes up.